# Can this algorithm be reversed in better than O(N^2) time?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, ranking, lexicographic-ordering

Say I've got the following algorithm to [biject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_function) `bytes -> Natural`:

```py
def rank(s: bytes) -> int:
    k = 2**8
    result = 0
    offset = 0
    for i, w in enumerate(s):
        result *= k
        result += w
        offset += (k**i)
    return result + offset
```

The decoder (at least to the best of my limited abilities) is as follows:

```py
def unrank(value: int) -> bytes:
    k = 2**8
    # 1. Get length
    import itertools
    offset = 0
    for length in itertools.count():  #! LOOP RUNS O(N) TIMES !#
        offset += (k**length)  #! LONG ADDITION IS O(N) !#
        if offset > value:
            value = value - (offset - k**length)
            break
    # 2. Get value
    result = bytearray(length)
    for i in reversed(range(length)):
        value, result[i] = divmod(value, k)  # (Can be done with bit shifts, ignore for complexity)
    return bytes(result)
```

Letting `N ≈ len(bytes) ≈ log(int)`, this decoder clearly has a worst-case runtime of `O(N^2)`. Granted, it performs well (<2s runtime) for practical cases (≤32KiB of data), but I'm still curious if it's fundamentally possible to beat that into something that swells less as the inputs get bigger.

---

```py
# Example / test cases:

assert rank(b"") == 0
assert rank(b"\x00") == 1
assert rank(b"\x01") == 2
...
assert rank(b"\xFF") == 256
assert rank(b"\x00\x00") == 257
assert rank(b"\x00\x01") == 258
...
assert rank(b"\xFF\xFF") == 65792
assert rank(b"\x00\x00\x00") == 65793

assert unrank(0) == b""
assert unrank(1) == b"\x00"
assert unrank(2) == b"\x01"
# ...
assert unrank(256) == b"\xFF"
assert unrank(257) == b"\x00\x00"
assert unrank(258) == b"\x00\x01"
# ...
assert unrank(65792) == b"\xFF\xFF"
assert unrank(65793) == b"\x00\x00\x00"

assert unrank(2**48+1) == b"\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFE\xFF\x00"
```

Comment: I have a hard time to map your biject link with the given code. Can you confirm, that this is just about converting a string of bytes to the respective integer? If so, I would surprised if the complexity of a decent inverse algorithm exceeds log(n), where n is the input `value`.

Comment: @guidot What's n?

Comment: Are you stuck with this particular encoding?  If you used plain binary, you could take advantage of the built-in `int.to_bytes()` and `int.from_bytes()` methods, which are likely faster than anything that could be written in Python.  The only hard part would be determining the number of bytes you need to represent a number - I think `math.ceil(math.log(N + 1, 256))` will work.

Comment: > _Are you stuck with this particular encoding?_ < Yes, unless you can recommend a different **bijective** encoding. It must be possible to differentiate `b''` and `b'\x00\x00'` without out-of-band signalling, and there must not be any invalid or duplicate integers.

Comment: @guidot I want every possible octet string to correspond to a unique nonnegative integer, and I want every nonnegative integer to correspond to a unique octet string. The formal term for this is a "bijection", but I also included such a big pile of example cases to try to paint a more human "picture" of what I'm trying to do. The key things to note are that **(a)** the function is lossless; it can always be reversed, **(b)** the output has no "gaps". I agree that it seems like, in principle, it should be doable in O(N)—O(log(int))—time; I only asked this question because I can't get there.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude this question appears related to some work I did a long time ago to write a bijective compressor with arithmetic encoding.  Are you by chance working on something similar?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Perhaps similar—this is just the first pre-encoder component to [this larger project](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692437/188128). The pipeline is currently sketched out as `bytes -> int -> Annotated[Set[int], 'lambda self: all(i in range(N+len(self)-1) for i in self)'] -> Multiset[Annotated[int, 'lambda self: self in range(N)']]`. The idea is to use bijections the whole way through to avoid any waste (however small) of storage space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearer if you write your `rank` function like this:

```python
def rank(s: bytes) -> int:
    k = 2**8
    result = 0
    for w in s:
        result *= k
        result += w + 1
    return result
```

... that you can write `unrank` like this:

```python
def unrank(value: int) -> bytes:
    k = 2**8
    ret = bytearray(0)
    while value > 0:
        value -= 1
        value, digit = divmod(value, k)
        ret.append(digit)
    ret.reverse()
    return bytes(ret)
```

(thanks for providing test cases)

The above version of `unrank` is still quadratic due to the costs of operations on long integers, so here is a less readable version of the same algorithm that is actually O(n) in python:

```python
def unrank(value: int) -> bytes:
    ret = bytearray(value.to_bytes(value.bit_length()//8 + 1, 'little'))
    for i in range(len(ret)):
        byte = ret[i]
        # subtract 1
        j = i
        while byte == 0:
            ret[j] = 255
            j+=1
            if j >= len(ret):
                break
            byte = ret[j]
        if byte == 0:
            # borrow went off the end
            ret = ret[:i]
            break
        ret[j] = byte-1
    ret.reverse()
    return bytes(ret)
```

Comment: It seems faster, but still is quadratic, so doesn't answer the question. (Times for unranking with random 10000 bytes: 1481 ms unrank_original, 188 ms unrank_Matt, 0.045 ms unrank_Kelly)

Comment: `divmod` is used for simplicity.  Comment in OP indicates that it's acceptable.

Comment: Is that a reply to me? I didn't say anything about `divmod`.

Comment: Yes, the `divmod` is why it's still quadratic.  But in his question, OP indicates that he knows how to do it in constant time.

Comment: > _That's not possible, and I see no such indication from them._< @KellyBundy I stated as much in the original question, on the line in question; I'm not being misrepresented.

Comment: @MattTimmermans As written, this answer has O(N) long subtraction `-=` in an O(N) `while` loop. That seems to be O(N^2)—no different than the one I gave in the original question. Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude ` -= 1` should be constant amortized time, since only 2 bits are affected on average.

Comment: @MattTimmermans But all the unaffected bits are copied. That's not constant time.

Comment: The subtraction is in-place, and does not need to make a copy.  Are you sure that it does?

Comment: It's not in-place. Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude You mean you can do an equivalent of your divmod with bit shifts in constant time? How?

Comment: @KellyBundy (The fiddliness of python's all-operations-always-copy can and will be dealt with by migrating to GMP or some other mutable integer solution, maybe even outside of Python. That's a separate issue I'll deal with only after I've got an **algorithm that's inherently better than O(N^2)**, which is what I asked. I won't worry about implementation details until I have an algorithm that's not **inherently broken** in the first place.)

Comment: @MattTimmermans I see. If you're sure that (integer immutability notwithstanding) that operation's actually got an amortized average constant cost, then this does answer my question; thanks! (Also, thanks for the genius rewrite of the encoder function—I didn't realize it could also be transformed into something so cheap!)

Comment: @KellyBundy OK OK, I added an O(n) implementation of the same algorithm.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Kelly is pretty good, and provides a lot of valuable contributions.

Comment: Posted mine as well now after all. Its advantage is that it lets Python's C code do the job, and for that, their original way with "offset" seems to be the way to go.

Comment: [Simpler version](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVHLTsNADBTXfIVvXYsmJdAVVaTwIwhVG-G02642wXEq5Vu49AIfxdewedGCmNt6xh7v-P2z7mRf-fP5o5Uy3nzdvL1SCa1n44_qZFxLGVgvCPETFJ1Qk0UQ4CGHgU0KK1tHfid7havVBm4hHRRMEjR9i2E23TgrkWo7TFF-CQtnRRwtEIeGsmKwwQuC9Y6Ux9Fppg4Xyi7hmu1hy97w-fDyuzwtEuoQ59Ni1yiYzDH6R53DvdY_BLmGsr-ypK5qhfNfE6YTcUOXSst-TEyFB0ZRzSFHNSWbPqT67lGv1xpxTH46wHyIbw) (in my opinion), although about 3.5 times slower in my benchmark.

Comment: If I wasn't done with this, I'd implement as a finite state transducer...  which nicely connects to your fast implementation by proving that the simple offset length correction works.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I've read part of the Wikipedia article now. Would it iterate over the bytes only once, only forward? Anyway, [yet another](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVHLTsNADBTXfIVv3VVJSqARVaX2xoFvQKhKqdOs2HpXrlOab-HSC3wUX8PmpYji23rGnvHs57evpXR0uXxVUsSLn5vDDguoiHN6V6fcVrgEQ6IhXsO2FjwuIwhFsIIWTbZGNhZpL6XSs9kCppC2DEYJnGYkZ87rblcibtNuUXQLE2tELE60bgeE6253U4VjMEEYgo89KtIj1NRHaSwCOWlkXszrX7SXD_3g4D7L_oEGpqve5hU_Hvp4fkMv8Ew7PD8xOx4lAjXxzis93JkwnpCPOHYqpi4tFR46ijyHDFWfavqQZneP2Xyead2l3oc_fMIv).

Comment: [FST-ish solution](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVJRboMwDJX2ySn812QFOljZKqT2IlWFgmpaNJSEEDpxlv30ZzvUTjNDGGPTJs1SpOj52c9-8sub7uxZyev1tbVFsHm_ua0zqbJcGaOefajHH2xhf_DpebP0Pj0QzjygYCKIevqU5FAWIGC3hQiwapAYyzhJvlryoa5QhlilBCPkCVmcPHCPe_XvCvEfCvFMYf0_Bc87YgGtJPCJXUTVYkocyyHYQd5ZbNKhuJS6tTTCwAgtSfc5VxDmpc0qlCd7Zny12sASyIJFVVpb4cKJq9a6Bn2dMEZ0zCVqwma7fJ90UHUD9JH7jr4XhwlzjUOhNcojy11T8qOGspkMSH_StdJsPlho8IKmwRE0aFsj3f7MMcgpbcgYNloV3UfJ3WOyXiecu5MZL-fzgj4A). Is this close to what you had in mind?  I don't see the nice connection to mine that you alluded to.

Comment: yes, but actually [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVK7TsMwFJUY8xVXYqitkpSURq0qYGRlYa8cctNYhOvIj1bhV1i6wEfBz2DiVG2hohIezz0vyef1vWltpWizeXO2jGcfZ58FluBIC3piK1E7nIMkyyG-hby1aOYR-CepcRZuoGMkVi26GwuKJJd2USMtbcX4cMpHo9kFDGppbY0D3umVs8HgWye0Fi0Lh1xprdb-cCdqgx1UKg3CJ4bQkN91KIEFOt-B_UHANYwP0V1sIpoGqWBiOM4m_ICEPvSkLB7zX5QjvY_79eXSUynjLPsj5UE7_EfxNFj6DsFppziHSi4rNBZIUfyCWnVfA8_OQ5VYIeSIBOmewChoND5iIWm5bbYWBoyw0pQSiwTgnuoWbIVQC-_zqMhKcv6uaM9IGv-1fjmySKIfzRvVsP3FJBpXqA32oEbrNIVhssDgUdRov1jWbzi9SrPLaTaZZJyHjfdT307-Cw).  Only 2 states implies that a single `if` is all you need to correct `offset` length.

Answer (score 1):

The reversal algorithm in plain English is like this:

1. Write down the hexadecimal representation of the number; if the number of digits is odd, prepend a leading zero.
2. Group the digits in pairs.
3. For each pair viewed as a number 0 to 255, starting from the rightmost (least significant) one:

   - Subtract 1 from the pair modulo 256
   - If there is an overflow, carry over to the pair to the left; if there is no pair to the left, remove the pair that caused the overflow. (You only ever need to subtract 1 or 2 at each step).

It is clear that the complexity is O(N) (N being the number of digits) provided you have access to the individual bits of the input.

Answer (score 1):

A faster linear solution:

```
def unrank(value: int) -> bytes:
    N = value.bit_length() // 8 + 1
    offset = int.from_bytes(b'\1' * N)
    if offset > value:
        N -= 1
        offset >>= 8
    return (value - offset).to_bytes(N)
```

Times for unranking with random 10000 bytes:

```
1433.748 ms  unrank_original
 192.317 ms  unrank_Matt
   1.877 ms  unrank_Matt2
   0.049 ms  unrank_Kelly
```

Benchmark code, includes some correctness checks ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVbdjuI2FL6t8hRnxQUOCxlgxQohgVTtVqtRu5mqs72arlAgJ4MhsSPbGYqqvkRve7M37UP1aeo_QpJlRi03Mz4-f9_5Ptv58-_ypHacffnyV6Wy0fyfb_7IBC-AKhSK81wCLUouFJSCp9VWBX7JZWD9FC2wdkGRrbe8YjoWEmn3giBIMQORsAORC9icFMoQRiugTC0C0L8DLGE6GMztQqCscqUtY7vkWSbxssy4ADqEow4GZFWBIlFIZOgSNeIHSzh0ba-XcKxtPrG2kcNgQENfXFWC1f7eySOomMGw5oI-Upbk5CnJK1wYGBaOBXYFUA8mEXzQpXJkj2pnbX5c9Yifg-pCDNjaNbLjJeFCZ34FP9zd_Qg__Rzfwx2JQ_h0-_G7e3jVewalSxf6yPgDfPv-_e2n27sYbn2CRijNztErcFDrLfOzJt2s-zsC4p1HcCnUCtgITA5-IlM3ERvbZt1MMREiOZFmDku7GYPAJxQSU6KpeMSzT4N-m3Lo8z3QzzplSp8KnhK_czDwgbxLGGwQUs4QjlTPeEMVyB3NlBwCfWRcoK265UWZ469UnVoKsWQTVyVs6-N7zPPTC-KIz0OLdMm1Q0BCuLmBuVbcpC0FHR-ZU7Z2BTf9XyZ9GEDsmnmBohhGS5-skXC1WsK8iYOc6XMOYaS4LxV3YH1MlPqvkhfYpnLs2j3uaI5eMCsYd0hrN-zZSvVZU1c4bBxtFSVliSwl1rdmKfJSIVd565Jm0E1fgNdF5Aish_U1nzc3ls0h9HOqVI79sKvks4BtNw0Fm4y6lrZq-dbWHshqo0SyVY0h7Y1C6pUbrwtfNsfrATzszWmYzmatjf3r5aRl0KLag9bJubV2HtthfZKv9Ly_9KwzPdNNDzZcCH6EIzJltAdqh_pCT7s9-6SLxiS-7qDGZqqNJv9DAVnFtlIHdq72YVMWrcV02DrmQdCDdxoJbhVDKa2itjvcHuonSRgE9um78J8Z_m3py1QSKfUFDxkRoZmXflu1Y3wRylufz5hLY_avMXkYOIdZOAT_73SmdTedvQ0_m4uwxEQt4waNrkE3h1LL0q25jCodnvKCTMbjsbZrbPclYhrUGDo-xukaHjXWAebp95M3oNxGbdc3jnLPXCn0cSNZ_zc1mOCbxTx6k_0OhYT-ELJovWZJget16D5N_BfK-UvlXw)):

```py
from itertools import product
import os
from time import perf_counter as time


def rank(s: bytes) -> int:
    k = 2**8
    result = 0
    offset = 0
    for i, w in enumerate(s):
        result *= k
        result += w
        offset += (k**i)
    return result + offset


def unrank_original(value: int) -> bytes:
    k = 2**8
    # 1. Get length
    import itertools
    offset = 0
    for length in itertools.count():  #! LOOP RUNS O(N) TIMES !#
        offset += (k**length)  #! LONG ADDITION IS O(N) !#
        if offset > value:
            value = value - (offset - k**length)
            break
    # 2. Get value
    result = bytearray(length)
    for i in reversed(range(length)):
        value, result[i] = divmod(value, k)  # (Can be done with bit shifts, ignore for complexity)
    return bytes(result)


def unrank_Kelly(value: int) -> bytes:
    N = value.bit_length() // 8 + 1
    offset = int.from_bytes(b'\1' * N)
    if offset > value:
        N -= 1
        offset >>= 8
    return (value - offset).to_bytes(N)


def unrank_Matt(value: int) -> bytes:
    k = 2**8
    ret = bytearray(0)
    while value > 0:
        value -= 1
        value, digit = divmod(value, k)
        ret.append(digit)
    ret.reverse()
    return bytes(ret)


def unrank_Matt2(value: int) -> bytes:
    ret = bytearray(value.to_bytes(value.bit_length()//8 + 1, 'little'))
    for i in range(len(ret)):
        byte = ret[i]
        # subtract 1
        j = i
        while byte == 0:
            ret[j] = 255
            j+=1
            if j >= len(ret):
                break
            byte = ret[j]
        if byte == 0:
            # borrow went off the end
            ret = ret[:i]
            break
        ret[j] = byte-1
    ret.reverse()
    return bytes(ret)


funcs = unrank_original, unrank_Matt, unrank_Matt2, unrank_Kelly

# Correctness
def check(s):
    r = rank(s)
    for f in funcs:
        assert f(r) == s
for N in range(6):
    for p in product([*range(5), *range(251, 256)], repeat=N):
        check(bytes(p))
check(os.urandom(1000))

# Speed
r = rank(os.urandom(10000))
for f in funcs:
    t0 = time()
    f(r)
    t = time() - t0
    print(f'{t*1e3:8.3f} ms ', f.__name__)
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  I had expected the offset length correction to be more complicated.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yeah, I'm quite happy with how simple that turned out. I think for that, it really helps to think of offset separately, so that (in rank()) it's an addition of an int with ≤N bytes and an int with N bytes. Then it's obvious that the sum has either N or N+1 bytes. I don't easily see that when thinking of the many embedded +1 of your modified rank().